# Starting activity/collecting data/destroying

Tags: java, android

I would like to have 2 activities, in one activity 2 textboxes and in another acitivity Map.

When I click on Textbox in first one, to open another one, pick place, click Done and close Map, destroy that activity, and fill 1st text box in first acitivty with choosen place. When I click another textbox, need to open same map acitivity but from start.

Any tips how to do that in a right way, opening 2nd acitivty, transfer data in textbox in first one, destroy 2nd, and same again.

This question is without code, it doesn't need to post code from acitivities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the second activities intent with startActivityForResult() method. After user picked the place in the map, but the put the String that you got from your map into intent before finishing second activity. Then at your first activities onActivityResult method, get the String you put into Intent and set it into your Textbox.

You can find detailed tutorial here:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html